# missing dependencies on the Quarkus extension artifacts marked with '-',how to relove it?

Tags: quarkus

envirment: win11
quarkus version: 2.10.0.Final

build error when i use `mvn install` to build quarkus extension.
i had try running `mvn install -e -U`,it had no effect.

this is log

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-extension-maven-plugin:2.10.0.Final:extension-descriptor (default) @ quarkus-seata ---
[WARNING] The POM for io.seata:quarkus-seata-deployment:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[ERROR] Quarkus Extension Dependency Verification Error
[ERROR] Deployment artifact io.seata:quarkus-seata-deployment::jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT was found to be missing dependencies on the Quarkus extension artifacts marked with '-' below:
[ERROR] -     io.quarkiverse.seata:quarkus-seata::jar
[ERROR] -     io.quarkus:quarkus-arc-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -         io.quarkus:quarkus-core-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -     io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -         io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-common-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -             io.quarkus:quarkus-mutiny-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -                 io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-context-propagation-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -             io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -                 io.quarkus:quarkus-netty-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -         io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-http-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -         io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonp-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -     io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-reactive-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -         io.quarkus:quarkus-jaxrs-client-reactive-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -         io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-stork-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -         io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-config-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -     io.quarkus:quarkus-agroal-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -         io.quarkus:quarkus-datasource-deployment::jar
[ERROR] -         io.quarkus:quarkus-narayana-jta-deployment::jar
```

i had add dependencies in this `pom.xml`,can you help me to reslove it?
this is `pom.xml` of deployment.

[image]

Comment: Does the runtime part of your extension depend on the corresponding modules?

Comment: yes，it depend `quarkus-arc`,`quarkus-resteasy-reactive`,`quarkus-rest-client-reactive`,`quarkus-agroal` and i had added them in deployment pom.xml

Comment: https://github.com/naah69/quarkus_seata
this is my git repo

Comment: Have you created that from the template we have?

Comment: yes, i had reslove it.there is error in `configuration.deployment` of  extension-descriptor